# How to count actual number of operations in running C++ program?

Tags: c++, profiler, machine-instruction

I am working with a big C++ project on VMware (Ubuntu). It has several processes and a lot of cpp files.

What I want to find out is this: While running my code, how many operations (Additions, multiplications, read, write, shift, etc...) are being performed in each of the cpp files.

I have searched a lot for this and I know that I should be looking for a profiler that gives me the number of instructions in the running code, but I didn't find any profiler yet.

I am a beginner in programming, so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Since it is a big program, you may find that the number of instructions executed in the routines you have source code for is very small, as a percentage, compared to library and system routines like `new`, `delete`, and I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind is probably what you're looking for. Just install it from your package manager, and then run the program by adding `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` to the beginning of the command line.

Comment: I tried it, but if I understand correctly, it gives the total number of instructions of the entire program.
If I want to get the different operations (Additions, divisions, etc..) per function, is there a way to do that with valgrind??

Answer (score 0):

Whilst valgrind is a great tool for linux, on Windows you're best off with the profiler built-in in Visual Studio; note that you need full version rather than free Express.